# When I open my workspace with eclipse, eclipse thinks it is a project

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, project, workspace

Up until now I was using eclipse whenever I was programming in Java. But I wanted to switch to IntelliJ.

I was trying to create a new project in my workspace and it said: `.idea already exists. Overwrite?`. I clicked `Yes` and it opened my workspace without the project I wanted to create.

I tried reopening IntelliJ, but it still wasn't there, so out of curiosity I opened eclipse, but now eclipse seems to think that my `workspace` is a project and there are `.metadata`, `src` and `workspace.iml` files/folders in my workspace. I tried deleting them and reopening my `workspace`, but eclipse still seems to  think `workspace` is a project and doesn't show my actual projects. Instead it shows the default options to create a new project, load a project, etc.

Is there a easy way to revert whatever I did with my `workspace`, so eclipse opens it normally again?

Comment: Deleting the `.metadata` folder is always a pretty bad idea, since it contains most of the preferences and other things you probably want to keep. If you cannot recover it, create or switch to a new workspace and import the projects from the workspace that has been damaged by IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem!

Comment: You could have checked for a `.project` file in the workspace root folder, deleting it or moving to another location could have fixed the problem.